# How to access otrs html page?

Tags: otrs

I want to access otrs html page to change the customer page that came after login page. I have search over remote server where the otrs is located but did not found the html page. Any body know where i can get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OTRS does not use pure HTML pages but it uses templates in what it calls `.dtl` format, which basically is valid HTML with placeholder tags which are rendered when accessing the pages.

The files are located in `<OTRS DIRECTORY>/Kernel/Output/HTML/Standard/`. The template for the customer login page is called `CustomerLogin.dtl` and is located in this directory.

The `<OTRS_DIRECTORY>` is dependent on your OS and installation. Most typically, on Linux, this would be `/opt/otrs` and on Windows it would be `c:\OTRS\OTRS`.

This said, for many changes to the Customer Portal, such as changing some of the text, or placing a logo, you actuallty don't need to modify the templates at all but you can do this by changing the configuration via the web interface. Please read the documentation for this.

Also, starting OTRS version 3.4 which will be out this summer, OTRS will no longer use the home-brew 'dtl' templates but it will rather use [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/), a standard Perl templating engine, as its templating solution. This will mean the extension of the templates will change from `.dtl` to `.tt` then.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But i dont need that page. I want to access the page what the customer will get after login.

Comment: Well, you'll need to be more specific because it depends on what you're trying to do! For instance the navigation is in a different template file from the new ticket screen, or the ticket overview screen. But just open a few files in the template directory with your web browser and I'm sure you'll be able to find out yourself.

Comment: You covered it all michchielb, just to add one thing if you do edit a dtl file its best to create a theme for all these modifications you want to do. see documentation [here ](http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/3.0/en/html/themes.html). I suppose this wont really matter if the dtl design is going to be replaced by the .tt templates.

Comment: joecop is correct, and one of the best reasons for using the separate theme is it makes it easier to see *what* your local modifications were. Alternatively, if you're using OTRS 3.2 or up, it is also possible to put your modified .dtl file in Custom/Kernel/Output/HTML/Standard/... - this way you don't need the theme at all and you still have nicely separated out your modifications.