# Change the alphabetical ordering of dynamic field entries (not dynamic fields) in customer Interface

Tags: otrs

I want to change the alphabetical ordering of the dynamic field values in customer interface (instead I want the ordering based on their key values entered initially).

**Dont want to change the ordering of dynamic fields rather the entries of dynamic fields (currently taking the albhabetical order)**

I need the help for this config. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the order manually. 
you will need to modify the dtl files though.

First you will need to comment out the block that inserts ALL the dynamic fields

block will look something like this after you comment it out:

```
#<!-- dtl:block:DynamicField -->
#                    <div class="Row Row_DynamicField_$QData{"Name"}">
#                        $Data{"Label"}
#                        <div class="Field">
#                            $Data{"Field"}
#                        </div>
#                        <div class="Clear"></div>
#                    </div>
#<!-- dtl:block:DynamicField -->
```

Then for each dynamic field yo uwill need to add a block. so if you have 5 dynamic fields you will need to add 5 blocks.

This example is for a dynamic field called "CAPA"

```
<!-- dtl:block:DynamicField_CAPA -->
                    <div class="Row Row_DynamicField_$QData{"Name"}">
                        $Data{"Label"}
                       <div class="Field" id="fielddfA6" >
                            $Data{"Field"}
                        </div>
                       <div class="Clear"></div>
                    </div>
<!-- dtl:block:DynamicField_CAPA -->
```

Replace everywhere it says CAPA with the name of the dynamic field.  and put the blocks in the order you want.

Note though that the dtl files will be replaced by tt template files in releases to come based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24030304/1314532)

Also when changing dtl files  you should do it in a theme. but not sure if this is important since dtl files will be replaced soon.

hope this helps. cheers.

Edit: dtl files can be found here under \Kernel\Output\HTML\Standard